# struts email application .Dynamic Html content for the email body

Tags: java, string, email, struts

In a struts2 application I want email notification is to be sent when ever a user is logged in .

I want the mail body to be Html content, with the data entered by the User in run time.

Can any one suggest suggest the best way to do it !

Foe now iam using mail.jar and iam able to send the static content easily.
But facing difficulty 
1. maintaining the long HTMl code string . 
2. How to substitute the values in the string with the dynamic values

Please can somebody help me with a proper solution. Or Best practice to follow in Email application !

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put the email body in a properties file and read it from there.
2. For substitution, you can define "placeholder" in your String like {FIRSTNAME} {LASTNAME} etc., and then do a replaceAll for the dynamic portions in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What u need to look into is "freemarker". Its a library and u can achieve your purpose with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) Editor like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), letting the user writing the html without even knowing html.

Then, after the user submitted the body, you take the output that is pure html, 
and inject it into the mail body.

End of story...

Just remember to set mimetype to `text/html` and not to `text/plain` , or you will see the tags instead of their representation...